# ElasticSearch - How to query data between two period in hash

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

In DB Postgresl, i have two column are `from` and `to` as below:

```
from: {"date": Date.new(2018,9,20)}
to: {"date": Date.new(2018,9,30)}
```

Currently, i use ElasticSearch to search and i want to take out all record have time period from `from["date"]` to `to["date"]`. I have tried to search but no result, can you help me?

Comment: Did you read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html ?

Comment: I've read it, but isn't a hash. If my column has format `from: "2018-09-29"` then i can use it.

Comment: I found a solution: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/complex-core-fields.html